# How to create looped output with knitr?

Tags: loops, knitr

In my thesis, I have found 79 different concepts I need to describe in detail in the appendix. I used R for the analysis, and I want to use knitr for creating that appendix.

Each description follows the same basic "template" filled with the values for one concept. The template is not overly complicated, but still needs several LaTeX commands with the values embedded.

Had it been only one concept description, I would have written straightforward LaTeX and inserted the values with `\Sexpr{}`. Now that I need to loop through a dataframe, the only way I know is to use a chunk and output the LaTeX commands from it with `cat`. Which makes basically unmaintainable code.

Is there a better way to solve that problem?

---

Here is an MWE which only outputs the name of the concept on a minipage. In reality, the dataframe will have 7-8 columns, and all of them will have to be typeset in a certain way on that minipage, including one graph (a histogram) per concept.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\begin{document}

<<createExampleData, echo=FALSE>>==
all.concepts.in.detail <- data.frame(name=c("red","green","blue", "purple", "yellow", "orange"))
@

 <<AllConceptsInDetail, echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'>>=
 for(rownumber in 1:nrow(all.concepts.in.detail)) {
  cat("\\begin{minipage}{\\textwidth}\n")
  cat("\\section{")
  cat(as.character(all.concepts.in.detail[rownumber, "name"]))
  cat("}\n")
  cat("\\end{minipage}\n\n")
 }
 @

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get your `cat()` output working I think you need to specify `results='asis'`. Like:

```
<<echo=F, results='asis' >>=
```

I believe this does the trick. But I am not an expert. I use this to directly output latex into my document in multiple ways. Most handy are loops with images which output a lot of images at once or tables.